# How to convert Below SQL query into Laravel Query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT tb_staff_primary.staff_name 
    ORDER BY tb_staff_primary.staff_name DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
       as staffs,
      tb_subject.subject_name, tb_subject.subject_code 
from tb_subject_allocation,tb_subject,tb_staff_primary,tb_batch 
where tb_subject_allocation.subject_id=tb_subject.subject_id 
  and tb_subject_allocation.staff_id=tb_staff_primary.staff_id 
  and tb_batch.batch_id=1 
GROUP by subject_code
```

i  need Laravel query for this sql Query

Comment: Hi! Please note that SO is not a "please fix my code" platform. Show us what you've tried and where you got stuck. We like to answer questions, not be somebody's free code provider ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write query by using your model objects like

```
$task_list = tb_subject_allocation::join('tb_subject', 'subject_id', 'subject_id')
                            ->join('leads_staff_details', 'leads_staff_details.staff_id', 'tb_staff_primary.staff_id')
                ->where('tb_batch.batch_id', 1)
                ->groupBy('subject_code')
                -select(DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT tb_staff_primary.staff_name 
    ORDER BY tb_staff_primary.staff_name DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
       as staffs'), tb_subject.subject_name, tb_subject.subject_code )
         or simply by using
```

DB::select("SQL QUery");

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are better ways to do it in Laravel but well you can use \DB::select

```
$yourVariable=\DB::select("yourSQLScript");
```

or you can use the \DB::raw() for GROUP_CONCAT column

```
$yourVariable=\DB::table('tb_subject_allocation as s1')
    ->join('tb_subject as s2','s1.subject_id','=','s2.subject_id')
    ->join('tb_staff_primary as s3','s1.staff_id','=','s3.staff_id ')
    ->join('tb_batch as s4','s1.batch_id','=','s4.batch_id')
    ->where('s4.batch_id','=','1')
    ->groupBy('subject_code')
    ->select('s2.subject_name','s2.subject_code',
        \DB::raw("GROUP_CONCAT(
               DISTINCT tb_staff_primary.staff_name 
               ORDER BY tb_staff_primary.staff_name DESC SEPARATOR ',') 
               as staffs")
     ->get();
```